# automake configure ignoring option --with-libxml2=yes

Tags: gcc, makefile, autotools, autoconf, automake

I am trying to compile, libgphoto2 with libxml2 support followint the guidelines [here](http://credentiality2.blogspot.com.es/2010/07/libgphoto2-gphoto2-build-from-svn-and.html). Everything is ok until I try to run ./configure:

> ./configure --prefix=/tmp/gphoto2/local --with-libxml2=yes

That appears to me as a correct syntax, however I got an output:

> LIBXML2 to support Olympus ..: no

I have checked this in 2 different systems (LinuxMint 11 x64 and Ubuntu 13.04), and I have found the same problem.

- Can anyone give me a clue or solution?
- Is there any problem with the syntax?
- Is there a common problem with the configure --with-PACKAGE[=yes] option?
- Is there a common problem with LIBXML2 used in compilation?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found another way. Thanks for your help.

After digging in the config.log file created after the ./configure tool, I found the libxml2 error (that I wrongly supposed to stop the configure script):

```
conftest.c:75:27: fatal error: libxml/parser.h: No such file or directory
```

But I knew it was there but can't find it! So I checked it and found it under

```
/usr/lib
```

And found somewhere else that libxml2 package comes with a script (xml2-config) to give library linking information and more so:

```
$ xml2-config --cflags
-I/usr/include/libxml2
```

And the just needed to add the output to the CFLAGS environment variable when configuring:

```
$ CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/libxml2" ./configure --prefix=/tmp/gphoto2/local --with-libxml2=yes
```

And everything else was just ok!

Answer (score 3):

This problem as appears on Debian Wheezy (Linux debian 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.41-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux) and the latest libgphoto2 release 2.5.2

libxml2-dev package is installed :-
Package: libxml2-dev
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Multi-Arch: same
Version: 2.8.0+dfsg1-7+nmu1

Not totally familiar with configure scripts
    but configure.ac file has line:-
        AC_CHECK_HEADER(libxml/parser.h,[
which I assume looks for libmxl/parser.h

the libxml2-dev package delivers the file
        /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h

It looks like libgphoto2 is designed for libxml2 library in a different place
Tried various solutions but only the following worked

as root I sym linked libxml2 to the place libgphoto2 was looking

> ln -s /usr/include/libxml2/libxml /usr/include/libxml

After compiling libgphoto2 and gphoto2 this enabled gphoto2 to talk to my Olympus E-510

Bug raised on gphoto sourceforge site (https://sourceforge.net/p/gphoto/bugs/953/) and a patch fix has been provided

Answer (score 1):

Usually, a `--with-some-package=yes` option checks for the existence of header files for `some-package` on your system. If it doesn't find the required header files, then it still outputs "no" to the terminal. Have you installed your distribution's `libxml2-devel` (or similarly named) package?

Comment: Yes, I already have everything ok, I mean the libxml2-dev package, etc. See below for the solution I found!